# How to install OpenGL for Qt 5

Tags: windows, qt, opengl

How we can install the OpenGL library on local machine (OS Windows 7, 64) with Qt 5 (32bit) ?

Comment: "One does not simply install OpenGL" Sean Bean

Answer (score 1):

By default your machine will have some version of openGL.
You can't install openGL yourself.
You need to update graphics driver of your machine. By doing so you will get latest version of openGL supported by your machine.

Answer (score 0):

For those who faced the same problem during the compilation of the source code using OpenGL lib and Qt5, I have resolved this by adding the following OpenGL lib in my pro file :

```
LIBS += -LD:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\lib\libQt5OpenGL.a -lopengl32
```

The `D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\lib\libQt5OpenGL.a` is the path to the lib file `libQt5OpenGL.a`.